# Rails -- Add a line break into a text area

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, textarea

I got a rails app where I can input a few paragraphs of text into my model.  The problem is I dont know how to input any line breaks.

I've tried to add " {ln}{/ln} ;  {&nbsp}  and {br}{/br}"  but that only displays the html as text and no break.

Is there anyway I can set it so the text area control will use any of the html I place within the model entry?

Is there any thing I can type so rails will recognize, hey put a line here?

Comment: Where does it not render correctly?  Within the actual textarea when you go back to edit the value (i.e. `<%= f.text_area :description %>`)?  Or on the page when you're rendering the value plainly (i.e. `<%= obj.description %>`)?

Comment: on the page where I'm trying to render the data it just places the < br > as text

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The problem isn't so much editing the value as it is rendering it later.  To add newline characters to your value while editing it in a textarea, just hit the return key.  When you re-edit that value later, the whitespace should still be there.

Rendering the whitespace is the tricky part.  In HTML, whitespace is generally insignificant.  A renderer like the one your browser uses will display a single space for any continuous string of whitespace.  So merely dumping the value onto the page won't be enough:

```
<%= obj.description %>
```

Even though your value may be `"One  \t  \n  \n  Two"`, it will show up on the screen as `"One Two"`.

To get those new line characters to actually separate the lines when displayed, you'll need to convert them to HTML before rendering:

```
<%= obj.description.gsub(/\n/, '<br/>') %>
```

Of course, if users are entering data that will be included in your HTML, you should be escaping the values to protect against [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).  If new lines are the only thing you need to support, it should be as simple as this:

```
<%= h(obj.description).gsub(/\n/, '<br/>') %>
```

If you want to allow more complex formatting, look into [Markdown](http://deveiate.org/projects/BlueCloth/) and [Textile](http://redcloth.org/) (both of which Rails provides helper view methods for).  Just be sure to investigate what if any support they provide for XSS prevention.

Comment: As of Rails 3, you'll have to add .html_safe: <%= h(obj.description).gsub(/\n/, '<br/>').html_safe %>

Answer (score 113):

Line breaks in textareas are produced as `\n'. However, the problem is that if you simply dump it into your view, it will just be line breaks in your HTML source.

You can try using the Rails `simple_format` helper to take care of some of this for you: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M002285

It will auto-convert line breaks to HTML tags. You can use it with something like `<%= simple_format(my_text_field) %>`.

Comment: For the record, to avoid XSS attacks you should be escaping the var like this: <%= simple_format h(my_text_field) %>

Comment: @tomeduarte simple_format sanitizes by default, h() isn't needed. This is an old post...maybe this functionality is new.

Comment: @tybro0103 it's rails 3 specific, introduced in https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/84d387bc0f3f3f6641b08d0ce40e924f09105c19 - 2010/06/17; Either I didn't know or assumed rails 2.x (can't remember). Thanks for mentioning it for the following readers! :)

Comment: The problem with simple_format is that it is too clever. It will preserve any \n in your text, but it will assume that two \n's are meant to indicate a new paragraph and will take your input and wrap specific parts of it in `<p>` tags. It really depends on what your needs are which method you should use. If you _absolutely_ must preserve all new lines, you should use the accepted answer. Otherwise use simple_format and plan for paragraph tags where you'll  be outputting this value.

Answer (score 33):

Keep user input unmodified and add this to your css:

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

It will display \r or \n (enter) in user input as a new line.

Comment: So much easier. Good answer.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: simple_format seems to only preserve 1 line break even though you have multiple when using in Mailer views. This answer works1

Comment: Wow, can't believe this was here all these years. And it's supported by every browser!

Answer (score 10):

Here is another way to display the line breaks in a string while still escaping the rest of the text:

```
<%= safe_join(@object.textarea_input.split("\r\n"), "<br />".html_safe) %>
```

Comment: I liked and added my own customised thing in it

Comment: Also you can use the `tag` helper, like this: `safe_join(@object.textarea_input.split("\r\n"), tag(:br))`

Answer (score 1):

What version of rails are you using?? Because the way to handle this, is different in rails 2 and 3.

Let's say the value of the record is `"foo<br />bar"`

In rails 3, if you want to evaluate the html, you could do `<%=raw "foo<br />bar" %>`, if you do so, you'll get a line break when you will see the view.

In rails 2 you don't have to do that, just do `<%= "foo<br />bar" %>`

Also, HTML doesn't get evaluated in a textarea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

See here http://code.byteblues.com/2012/03/23/preloading-a-text-input-area-text_area-with-data-that-contains-a-line-break/

```
<%=raw text_area_tag :keywords, keywords, :rows => 8 %>
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem with `simple_format` is that it's also adding other tags like `<b><i><hr><h1>`...
if you just want line breaks without other tags i suggest you build a partial (lets call it line_break):

```
<% text.split("\n").each do |t| %>
  <%= t %><br>
<% end %>
```

then, just call it from your view:

```
<%= render partial: 'line_break', locals: {text: some_text} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`\n` if memory serves (it hasn't been doing so well today... try at your own risk lol)

Edit: making the assumption you were talking about a `textarea`, if it is simple output, just use `<br>`

Comment: Nah I tried \n as well as the same within bracket and it still just output the code as if it were text

Comment: Could you provide the code you are using so we can get a better idea of what we are looking at instead of random guesses?

Comment: Sure thing... the view has 
 <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>

thats pretty much it.  I just wanted to turn off the html within the text area

Answer (score 0):

The answers above were good:

- the `gsub` (@Ian) worked well
- the `simple_format` (@Karl) was a bit over the top as @Aaron pointed out, wrapping everything in `<p>`

So I tweaked as follows:

```
simple_format(value, {}, wrapper_tag: 'div')
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are wrong. Text area does not render 
 as line breaks, because the innerHTML value of the TEXTAREA element does not render HTML..

You need to add the Line feed HTML entity: `&#10;`

**EXAMPLE:**

```
<textarea><%= "LINE 1&#10;LINE 2&#10;LINE 3".html_safe %></textarea>
```

See also [New line in text area - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area)

Answer (score -2):

If you are simply displaying your string in the view. then try it with

```
< p >This is my text< / p >< br />
```