# escape HTML output but no line-breaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a description text field in my Model.
No I want to add this description on the show page. 
But the text renders ugly because of no linebreaks.

If i replace them with `<br/>` then the rails escape them with.
So i tried to use the raw() method.
I want to escape bad HTML but have the linebreaks in my output.

I end up with some ugly code.

```
raw(h(@place.description.gsub("\n","#linebreak#")).gsub("#linebreak#","<br/>"))
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you should use the simple_format helper:

```
<%= simple_format @place.description %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

Comment: It is worth noting that this is safe from xss in newer versions of rails. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137393/rails-add-a-line-break-into-a-text-area

Answer (score 3):

3 years later, but it's never too late to provide a good working solution

This will escape all HTML chars but the newlines (compatible Linux, Windows and Mac)

```
html_escape(@place.description).gsub(/(?:\n\r?|\r\n?)/, '<br />').html_safe
```

Answer (score 2):

is what you are looking for

```
@place.description.html_safe.gsub("\n", '<br/>')
```

?  But on second thought, doesn't the `html_safe` usage like that make it easy for the site to get XSS attack?  (because it assumes the `description` is safe).

So won't a better solution be

```
<%= (h @place.description).gsub("\n", '<br/>') %>
```

at first I thought

```
<%= (h @place.description).gsub("\n", '<br/>'.html_safe) %>
```

is needed but actually both versions work.  I then tested by adding some HTML tags to `description` and it got escaped into `&lt;` etc, so it does prevent XSS attack.

Comment: I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that works:

```
<%= sanitize(@place.description.gsub("\n", "<br />"), :tags => %w(br), :attributes => %w()) %>
```

More reading:

[Parsing newline characters in textareas without allowing all html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253689/rails-parsing-newline-characters-in-textareas-without-allowing-all-html-tags)

Documentation:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

From sanitize:

This sanitize helper will html encode all tags and strip all attributes that aren’t specifically allowed.

It also strips href/src tags with invalid protocols, like javascript: especially. It does its best to counter any tricks that hackers may use, like throwing in unicode/ascii/hex values to get past the javascript: filters. Check out the extensive test suite.

You can specify allowed tags with :tags option, and attributes with :attributes option.