# Parsing newline characters in textareas without allowing all html tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping, html-safe

I have a textarea field where users can enter content. When it comes to displaying their entry on a page, rails returns `\n` for each line break, which appears as no break at all for html on the page.

From what I gather, the standard way of getting around this is a `.gsub` command, replacing `\n` with `<br />`, and then a `.html_safe` on the end to ensure the `<br />` renders.

The problem is, I don't want to html_safe the content - html should still be replaced, but `<br />` tags should be injected into the (non-escaped) content.

Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `simple_format` method is good for formatting line breaks. It wraps text blocks in `<p>` tags, and converts newline characters into line breaks (`<br>`) (double newlines breaks the following text into a second paragraph).

It doesn't however escape other html characters, and instead just allows them. For what you're after a combination of `simple_format` along with [sanitize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize) should do nicely. Try using this:

`<%=raw sanitize(simple_format(@article.body), :tags => %w(br p) ) %>`

Comment: Or even better yet, user the builtin `h()` method: `<%=simple_format h @article.body %>`

Comment: If you want to do this in a model or controller:
`ActionController::Base.helpers.raw ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize((ActionController::Base.helpers.simple_format( body )), :tags => %w(br p) )`

Comment: how to allow only "br"? If I add it, it doesn't allow multiple "br" lines

Comment: Just for those seeing this now, it appears that simple_format sanitizes by default now. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html

Answer (score 6):

If you want HTML tags entered in the text area visible, but still want line breaks to show, try this:

```
<%= simple_format(h @article.body) %>
```

The "h" quotes all the HTML special chars and "simple_format" then converts the line breaks to <br>.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want to do, you can store the `\n` as it is, and then, when displaying the content on screen, use `(h @comment.content).gsub("\n", '<br>')`, which is to first escape all HTML tags, and then replace the `\n` with the `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

All this can be avoided by using `&lt;pre&gt;` tags. This has the advantage of preserving tabbing as well. eg

```
&lt;pre&gt;&lt;%= @article.body %&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;
```