# How to add a new line in textarea element?

Tags: html, textarea, line-breaks

I want to add a newline in a textarea. I tried with `\n` and `<br/>` tag but are not working. You can see above the HTML code. Can you help me to insert a newline in a textarea?

```
<textarea cols='60' rows='8'>This is my statement one.\n This is my statement2</textarea>

<textarea cols='60' rows='8'>This is my statement one.<br/> This is my statement2</textarea>
```

Answer (score 635, accepted):

Try this one:

```html
    <textarea cols='60' rows='8'>This is my statement one.&#13;&#10;This is my statement2</textarea>
```

`&#10;` Line Feed and `&#13;` Carriage Return are [HTML entities<sup>wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). This way you are actually parsing the new line ("\n") rather than displaying it as text.

Comment: @LittleAlien https://jsfiddle.net/v0y3xvpx/1/ - answer based on the OP question, obviously problem was solved

Comment: isn't just `&#10;` enough to parse the `\n`?

Comment: Doesn't it depend on Windows vs. macOS whether both the line-feed and carriage-return characters are needed, or even parsed right?

Comment: @SeizeTheDay yes, but it is not MacOS - it is Linux/BSD vs Windows

Comment: @Bakudan Oh!  I thought macOS, being Unix-based, would still have that issue.  But you’re for sure right, the difference is more general.

Answer (score 100):

Break enter Keyword line in Textarea using CSS:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Comment: it is the simplest method to achieve the required result, thanks @Suraj

Comment: This is indeed a good solution, except if you plan to minify your HTML, you would have to preserve these newlines

Answer (score 46):

I think you are confusing the syntax of different languages.

- `&#10;` is (the HtmlEncoded value of ASCII 10 or) the linefeed character literal in a **HTML** string. But the line feed character does **NOT** render as a line break in HTML (see notes at bottom).
- `\n` is the linefeed character literal (ASCII 10) in a **Javascript** string.
- `<br/>` is a line break in HTML. Many other elements, eg `<p>`, `<div>`, etc also render line breaks unless overridden with some styles.

Hopefully the following [illustration](https://jsfiddle.net/0ebyLzzq/1/) will make it clearer:

```js
T.innerText = "Position of LF: " + t.value.indexOf("\n");

p1.innerHTML = t.value;
p2.innerHTML = t.value.replace("\n", "<br/>");
p3.innerText = t.value.replace("\n", "<br/>");
```

```html
<textarea id="t">Line 1&#10;Line 2</textarea>

<p id='T'></p>
<p id='p1'></p>
<p id='p2'></p>
<p id='p3'></p>
```

A few points to note about Html:

- The `innerHTML` value of the `TEXTAREA` element does not render Html. Try the following: `<textarea>A <a href='x'>link</a>.</textarea>` to see.
- The `P` element renders all contiguous white spaces (including new lines) as one space.
- The LF character does not render to a new line or line break in HTML.
- The `TEXTAREA` renders LF as a new line inside the text area box.

Comment: On the face of it this post seems complicated, but actually contains a LOT of useful information. If you are progamatically adding lines to your `<textarea/>` this is the post you need!

Comment: `<br/>` is what I was looking for

Comment: Very useful post indeed. Most newcomers will confuse these

Answer (score 36):

I've found `String.fromCharCode(13, 10)` helpful when using view engines. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode

This creates a string with the actual newline characters in it and so forces the view engine to output a newline rather than an escaped version. Eg: Using NodeJS EJS view engine - This is a simple example in which any \n should be replaced:

viewHelper.js

```
exports.replaceNewline = function(input) {
    var newline = String.fromCharCode(13, 10);
    return input.replaceAll('\\n', newline);
}
```

EJS

```
<textarea><%- viewHelper.replaceNewline("Blah\nblah\nblah") %></textarea>
```

Renders

```
<textarea>Blah
blah
blah</textarea>
```

---

replaceAll:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (find, replace) {
    var result = this;
    do {
        var split = result.split(find);
        result = split.join(replace);
    } while (split.length > 1);
    return result;
};
```

Comment: The newline = String.fromCharCode(13, 10); is the only thing that worked for me in adding new line programatically during run time. +1 on that.

Comment: I would like to suggest perhaps a simpler way for replace all: var regExp = new RegExp(find,"gi");
str=str.replace(regExp,replace);

Comment: I did `s = s.replace(/\\n/g, String.fromCharCode(13, 10) )`. This is magic though. Thank you.

Answer (score 32):

```
<textarea cols='60' rows='8'>This is my statement one.

This is my statement2</textarea>
```

Fiddle showing that it works: http://jsfiddle.net/trott/5vu28/.

If you really want this to be on a single line in the source file, you could insert the HTML character references for a line feed and a carriage return as shown in the answer from @Bakudan:

```html
  <textarea cols='60' rows='8'>This is my statement one.&#13;&#10;This is my statement2</textarea>
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this. It works:

```
<textarea id="test" cols='60' rows='8'>This is my statement one.&#10;This is my statement2</textarea>
```

Replacing for `<br>` tags:

```
$("textarea#test").val(replace($("textarea#test").val(), "<br>", "&#10;")));
```

Comment: its actually $("textarea#test").val().replace(/\n/g, "&#10;");
(this will replace all occurrences of new line)

Answer (score 7):

To get a new line inside text-area, put an actual line-break there:

```html
    <textarea cols='60' rows='8'>This is my statement one.
    This is my statement2</textarea>
```

Answer (score 6):

You should also check the css `white-space` property ([mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)) of your element, make sure it's set to a value that doesn't suppress line breaks, e.g.:

```css
white-space: pre-line;
```

You'd be interested in these 3 values:

> **pre** 
> Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are only broken at
> newline characters in the source and at <br> elements.
>
> **pre-wrap** 
> Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are broken at
> newline characters, at <br>, and as necessary to fill line boxes.
>
> **pre-line** 
> Sequences of white space are collapsed. Lines are broken at
> newline characters, at <br>, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to use `\n` instead of `/n`.

Comment: Well, a literal `\n` won't work either, it would need to be an *actual* newline.

Comment: Yes, of course. But I'm (incorrectly?) assuming that he already knew this.

Answer (score 2):

After lots of tests, following code works for me in Typescreipt

```
 export function ReplaceNewline(input: string) {
    var newline = String.fromCharCode(13, 10);
    return ReplaceAll(input, "<br>", newline.toString());
}
export function ReplaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My `.replace()`function using the patterns described on the other answers did not work. The pattern that worked for my case was:

```
var str = "Test\n\n\Test\n\Test";
str.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,'&#13;&#10;');

// str: "Test&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;Test&#13;&#10;Test"
```

Answer (score 0):

T.innerText = "Position of LF: " + t.value.indexOf("\n");

```
p3.innerText = t.value.replace("\n", "");

<textarea id="t">Line 1&#10;Line 2</textarea>

<p id='p3'></p>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using react**

**Inside the function**

```
const handleChange=(e)=>{
const name = e.target.name;
let value = e.target.value;
value = value.split('\n').map(str => <span>{str}<br/></span>);
SetFileds({ ...fileds, [name]: value });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and natural solution not involving CSS styles or numeric character references like `&#13;&#10;` would be to use the `&NewLine;` character entity reference:

```
The cardinal directions are:&NewLine;- North&NewLine;- East&NewLine;- South&NewLine;- West
```

---

**Note**: Since this is defined simply as the LF (line feed, or the `U+000A` Unicode code point) character, it's not 100% certain whether it suits situations where the entire CR + LF (carriage return + line feed) sequence is required. But then, it worked in my Chrome, Edge and WebView2 tests done on Windows 10, so it should be ok to use.

Answer (score -12):

just use `<br>` 

ex:

```
<textarea>
blablablabla <br> kakakakakak <br> fafafafafaf 
</textarea>
```

result:
blablablabla 
 kakakakakak 
 fafafafafaf