# How to dynamically add a new line in a textarea; javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a keyboard plugin. Which requires that if the user clicks on the <kbd>enter</kbd> key, then it must add the newline in that textarea.

I have tried adding other characters, such as a b c etc. But in case of newline I know a newline in js is added using

```
\n
```

But, when I try to append this to the textarea it just adds that to the textarea's text. While I want it to start a newline. How can I get the new line?

Here is the code that runs with each click:

```
$('#vboard li').click(function () {
  CurVal = $(LastFocused).val();
    $(LastFocused).val(CurVal + $(this).attr('id'));
    $(LastFocused).focus();
});
```

The above code executes and appends the current button's value to the element. When I click on enter key, it gives me output as value + '\n' for example:

If the value was afzaal, then after the click it would change to afzaal\n instead of starting a new line.

How would I get the newline in textarea?

Comment: Seems to work for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/UT6LL/1/

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a new new dynamicaly, right?
Give this a try and see if this is what you wanted.

```
$('textarea').html($('textarea').val()+'&#10;Something');
```

I'm setting `html` of textarea instead of its `val`

---

It seems even this works fine

```
$('textarea').val($('textarea').val()+'\nSomething');
```

Answer (score 2):

this one should work with vanila Javascript:

var newMessage="please add me to the new line";

const textarea = document.getElementById('messages');

element.value += "\n"+ newMessage;

Answer (score 1):

try somthing like

```
<textarea cols='60' rows='8'>This is my first line.&#13;&#10;This is my second line </textarea>
```

using  `&#10;` and `&#13;` will let you on new line without displaying in textarea

Comment: Same result brother, it adds `\n` to the value.

Comment: That's great in the HTML, and you found it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area), using entities, but setting the elements value with javascript entities won't work.

Comment: I like it , this works best for embedding a line break directly in text area.