# Newlines and carriage returns in a ZF2 form - why does zf2 edit the value I enter into a textfield

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2, textfield, carriage-return

&I have been trying to insert a formatted entry into a text area using ZF2 and need line breaks.  The consensus in blogs appears to be to use html entities to insert carriage returns and new lines.

I found a great explanation how to do this here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8627926/1325365

This solution works really well when copied and pasted.

However when I use this solution in a ZF2 form the framework appears to alter what appears for instance I have the following code:

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'content',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'textarea',
            'class' => 'wide',
            'id'    => 'content',
            'value' => 'This is my statement one.&#13;&#10;This is my statement2'
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Content:',
        ),
    ));
```

The critical code has been changed when I view source.  ZF2 has changed this to "&#13;&#10;".

The changes to prevent XXS means the critical code displays literally.

Any suggestions how I change this behavior? One option is to insert the text using javascript, but this seems to be a round about route.

Comment: There are no “additional semicolons”, but the `&` has been converted to `&amp;` (standard anti XSS measure). And I don’t see why there should be any need to use entities to get line breaks, a simple `\n` in a _double-quoted_ string should work just fine.

Comment: Good point, I have edited my question accordingly. But the problem remains with double quoted stings or /n everything displays literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a new line you can use this

```
'value' =>  'This is my statement one.' . PHP_EOL . 'This is my statement2'
```

Comment: I have not come across this before, but it works a treat thanks so much @Demo

Comment: It's like "\n" for *.nix systems ... I think.