# How to display text inside text area with line break instead of <br/>

Tags: javascript, html, newline

I have a Gridview with a textarea. when i have line breaks in the textarea it is corrrectly saving those line breaks to the database. but when i display the same i see it as `</br>` instead of a line break

[image]

[image]

So the Data is saved in the table as `test1<br/<br/><test2>`. This gets displayed properly in the view mode, but when i click the edit button to update the data i see the the `<br/>` tags instead of actual line breaks. How can i solve this issue?

This is differernt from the [New line in text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area) question as i do not have control over the innerText of the TextArea. This is being dynamically generated from the Database and i cannot change the contents of the DB as this would cause problems in the display in view mode

Comment: how do you submit it to the database? (using a servlet?). What you could easily do is, replace the string(textarea input) "<br/>" with "\n" and submit. have a look and see.  ex: var input= $("#txtarea1").text().replaceAll("<br/>","\n");