# Droppable item text with carriage return

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using a drag & drop functionality where i drag item and dropthe text in droppable item.

**Draggable Item :**

```
 <li id="test" data-text="Test \n Drag"><label>Test Drag</label></li>
```

**Droppable Item :**

```
<textarea id="testtextarea"></textarea>
```

I want to drop text from draggable item with carriage return

Means Output would be
Test is first line and drag in Second line

I am using following Jquery

```
$("li").draggable({
   // snap: false, snapMode: 'both', revert: false,
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    zIndex: 100,       
}); $("#testtextarea").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui, e) {
            $("#testtextarea").val($("#test").attr("data-text"));
        } });
```

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/60gfazwg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just check if **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/60gfazwg/3/)** is what you are looking for. You have to modify your data-text attribute as below

```
<li id="test" data-text="Test &#13;Drag">
       <label>Test Drag</label>
</li>
<textarea id="testtextarea"></textarea>
```

**[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area)**

Comment: Thanks. Have followed that post already and solved my problem.