# New line in textarea is not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add some dynamic text which has multiple lines in textarea control, but it is not working in IE.

I followed the solution provided in this discussion:

[New line in text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area)

Here is my **JS** code:

```
 var requestText = 'Hello, some text. &#13;&#10;' +
                   'Details are &#13;&#10;' +
                   'id: ' + user.Id+ '&#13;&#10;' +
                   'count: ' + user.Count;

$('#RequestContentTxtBox').append(requestText);
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="RequestContentTxtBox" rows="6"></textarea>
```

The above code works in Chrome but not in IE. I tried to add `</br>` instead of `&#13;&#10;` but that does not work in Chrome.

Is there any simple way to apply new line in textarea which works both in IE and Chrome?

Comment: What version of IE? Works on IE11 http://jsfiddle.net/2xwg1rzu/

Comment: @blex, I am having IE 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use \n

```
'Hello, some text.\n'
```

and you should use `val()` not `append()`