# Are there any html entities as an alternative for the "break" tag (<br>)?

Tags: html, html-entities

Are there any HTML Break alternatives for a break?

I don't mean `<br>`, `<wbr>` and `\n\r`, is there an HTML entity, something like `&1234;` ?

Comment: Here is another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area) which answer's cover HTML entities for line feed

Comment: Why not use styles? Like padding / margins? Couldnt you create a style for a class that creates the amount of space you want between elements, and then apply that class to the elements that should exhibit this "break" ?

Comment: @Todd there are certain situations where that kind of solution is feasible, perhaps the OP requires an HTML solution

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. I cant use padding / margins because I got a Mail from my hosted Server for each cronjob (and there not that much settings). I tried br-Tag and It works perfectly, but sometimes it fails because the line-break comes before the br-Tag is complete. That's why I need a pure HTML solution. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&#10;` is line feed. Check this [link](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

Comment: In those context where <br> are applicable \r and \n are white spaces, not line breaks.

Comment: Yep, noted. thanks for th epointer.