# In JavaScript the newline character is not actually creating a new line, is there an alternative or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, textbox, newline

I am trying to create a program that will output an XSL file.  Below is the code I am trying to use the '\n' does not actually create a new line, and the next value is put next to it.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("output");
        countOfAdd += 1;
        if (countOfAdd > 1){
            TheTextBox = "";
            countOfAdd = 1;
        }
        else if (countOfAdd == 1){
            //where all of the xsl output will be
            //line 1
            TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + '<?xml version="1.0"?>' + '\n';
            //line 2
            TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + '<!-- Sets up the stylesheet and declares the :xfa function in case you want to globalize fields -->';
```

EDIT:
I have already tried the br HTML field but due to this being a textbox I am adding to it simply includes it in the output

EDIT 2:
My example does not work already.  Not sure why but the text field simply ignore the \n completely.

Comment: Because in HTML newline is `<br>`, not `\n`?

Comment: I have used <br> as well, simply adds <br> to the text field

Comment: Wait, if it's a `<textarea>`, your example is going to work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6rh0j8gk/ how it doesn't, if it does.

Answer (score 1):

Gave up and changed it to a textarea instead of an input text field.. mistake on my end.  Works now, thanks all.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8627926/5620297).

You need to use the HTML entities `&#13;&#10;`. They create new lines rather than displaying a `\n` character.

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried this (should have mentioned in post) because it is a text field I am adding to it simply adds '<br>' to the output

Comment: @renegade_ghost I found something else, check it out (Using HTML entities)

Answer (score -1):

I see you are probably putting it in a text field.

If this is the case, try

```
&#13;&#10;
```

it should work in the text field.

Comment: Thanks, just gave it a whirl, it simply added to the output.

Comment: I just saw you used <input> with type text. This was doomed to fail, as only textarea is a input field that can display multiple lines.