# HTML New Line with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using this [reference](http://bootswatch.com/cerulean/#indicators), and the red alert option.  Here it is:

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>Oh snap!</strong> <a href="#" class="alert-link">Change a few things up</a> and try submitting again.
</div>
```

In their example, there is a line break after *try*.. is that just because of width?

My version:

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger" style="float:right;">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dissmiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>Leave blank if there is already a Record for today!&#13;&#10; This will auto-calculate based on the previous Record.</strong>
</div>
```

Now mine doesn't have any line break but I also haven't messed with the CSS.. but I was wondering if there was a way to put a line break within the `<strong>` inline?  I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area), but I guess that is strictly for `<textarea>`'s.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using <br/>?

Comment: @Lucas that is so strange because I tried this and the <br> wasn't rendering as an html tag.. it was just being inserted as part of the <strong> but now it is working.. thank you

Comment: yes, in fact that *is* just because of the width - just try to make your window smaller, then you'll see it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just put a `br` tag wherever you want a line break. Notice the new line after record in the example below, due to the inserted `<br>`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger" style="float:right;">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dissmiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>Leave blank if there is already a Record<br>for today!&#13;&#10; This will auto-calculate based on the previous Record.</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `<br/>` shouldn't be used for everything. Only use it for breaking up text. When you want a whole element to be on it's own line, use `display: block` in the CSS.

Comment: True, he could just surround the text that you want on a new line with a div instead of changing CSS.

Comment: Why are linebreaks not shown directly? Is there way to show them directly? I have users input text in a textbox and then want to show the saved text in a Bootstrap card, but that doesn't preserve/show the linebreaks.