# Insert new line in text only div

Tags: html, unicode, line-breaks

I'm working with a CMS that allows only text in a certain div (HTML , like `<br>`, is parsed to `&lt;br&gt;`). It is fine with Unicode / HTML codes (e.g. `&amp;` would generate `&` and `&#x00040;` would generate `@`) but it will seemingly not allow a new line / carriage return. How can I put a `<br>` in the div, without using HTML?

I've tried:

- `&NewLine;` - https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref
- `&#10;` - [New line in text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area)
- `&#13;` - [New line in text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area)
- `&#x0a;` or `&#xa;` or `&#x0000a;` - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline
- `&#x0d;` or `&#xd;` or `&#x0000d;` - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Here is a fiddle with the same issue (and HTML structure as output by CMS) > https://jsfiddle.net/w3p4wgcc/ ...Is it just not possible?

Comment: That just puts "\n" into the text sadly, same with `\r`

Comment: does your cms allows you to add inline css?

Comment: Is it possible to use javascript?

Comment: No, it has all the same problems as the CSS. I'm really looking for a solution for non technical people when they are copy-writing inside the CMS editor (e.g. at the moment they are happy with things like `&lsquo;` and `&pound;`)

Answer (score 30):

With inline css i've managed to do the following:

```
<div style="white-space: pre-wrap;">
This is some new text,&#10;this text should be on a new line.
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6mqgrym9/

If you need all of your divs to be like this one could say in your stylesheet the following:

```
div {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

if these divs are contained in a root div (which has a id) one could do the following:

```
#idhere > div {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

If you're allowed to use some javascript you can try this:

```
<div>
    <script>
        document.currentScript.parentNode.innerHTML = 'This is some new text<br>this text should be on a new line.';
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't edit the HTML in that way, but it might be possible to create a global class of some sort...

Comment: global class? a css class you mean? if you are able to that'd be even a more beautiful solution.. yet you still need to be able to add the class to the `div` element

Comment: Sorry, yes. A css class to the global stylesheet. The issue would be that I can't target divs individually with any great accuracy so I'd be mildly concerned that a change at a high level would have unseen (and undesirable) changes in other places.

Comment: Do these div's have anything uniques? Which seperates them from the other divs?

Comment: @tymothytym if this answer helped you out please set it as an sollution

Comment: Whilst it is helpful (I did up-vote), it unfortunately doesn't solve my original problem as I can't target the div with the css with a good enough accuracy.

Comment: the `\n` tags also are working after adding `pre-wrap`. thanks

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the following in CSS.

```html
div {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

The difference between pre-line, pre-wrap and pre is available under [this link](https://medium.com/@tohbansoon/differences-between-pre-pre-line-pre-wrap-and-no-wrap-in-css-1fe4b0f72699)