# String template - new line doesn't show

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use a template string to update infoDiv's text and for some reason all this text is in one line. What am I doing wrong? None of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811366) solutions work - they're just rendered.

```
infoDiv.textContent = `Hi!
It's a ${counter} question quiz.
It takes about ${time_minutes} minutes to solve it.
Are you ready?`
```

EDIT:

I found a CSS solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33052216/7445795) (`white-space: pre-line;`).

```js
let counter = 8;
let time_minutes = 3;

infoDiv.textContent = `Hi!
It's a ${counter} question quiz.
It takes about ${time_minutes} minutes to solve it.
Are you ready?`
```

```html
<div id="infoDiv" style="white-space: pre-line"></div>
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert new line in text only div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811366/insert-new-line-in-text-only-div)

Comment: DIVs only allow spaces.

Comment: `'\n'` as text content will be rendered as a space. You want a line break in HTML, you need to write `<br>`.

Comment: Thanks all, I found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980416/how-can-i-insert-new-line-carriage-returns-into-an-element-textcontent): adding `white-space: pre-line;` to div's css

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript. HTML renders line breaks as normal  spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Style the div with `white-space` CSS property.

```js
const counter = 22;
const time_minutes = 60;

infoDiv.textContent = `Hi!
It's a ${counter} question quiz.
It takes about ${time_minutes} minutes to solve it.
Are you ready?`
```

```html
<div id="infoDiv" style="white-space: pre-wrap"></div>
```