# Display &#xa; as Character in textarea

Tags: html, escaping, html-parsing

In my html page, I have a **textarea** tag and some text inside it. Later I will process the text.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">
            test&#xA;test
        </textarea>

    </body>
</html>
```

But in the output html page '& #xA;' (adding a space to avoid character from being invisible ) is being replaced with a newline. I want to see those characters as **character**. Basically I want to escape that from being parsed.

I did a lot of research
looked at [html escape characters](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php)  and did not find anything.

Also I looked at a SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area) and I want to do exact opposite.

You can look at the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/snqhbfzc/)

Is there any way to escape this character.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textarea` is an **[escapable raw text element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#elements-2:escapable-raw-text-elements-3)**, so any sequence of characters inside it that starts with "`&`" (ampersand) and that ends with a semicolon gets parsed as a [character reference](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-charref).

So to prevent the `&#xA;` in the `test&#xA;test` code snippet in the question from being parsed as a character reference for the newline character, the "`&`" just needs to be replaced with `&amp;`:

```
test&amp;#xA;test
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">
            test&amp;#xa;test
        </textarea>

    </body>
</html>
```