# Preserving new lines and spaces in text area not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, riot.js

I am using text area to enter text and on form submit, the text displayed in the view is not retaining any line breaks and spaces.

Text area:

```
<textarea type="text" id="topicDetails"></textarea>
```

Tried replacing text using the following:

```
postTopic(){
    var content = document.getElementById('topicDetails').value;
//            textcontent = content.replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1'+ "" +'$2'); 
//            textcontent = content.replace("\r\n", "\\r\\n"); 
//            textcontent = content.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
//            textcontent = content.replace(/\r?\n/g, '&#13');
//            var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';
//            textcontent = (content + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
    textcontent = content.replace(/\n/g,"<br>")

    var topic = {
        "topicId" : new Date().getTime(),
        "title": document.getElementById('title').value,
        "details": textcontent,
        "username": DataMixin.data.username,
        "userImage": "assets/img/Logos Divine Light/6.png",
        "dayPosted": new Date().toLocaleString()
    }

    console.log('posting blog..... ', topic);
    self.data.blogTopicsArr.push(topic);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/new_topic",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(self.data.blogTopicsArr),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (res) {
            console.log('res is ', res);
            if (res == 'Authentication failed'){
                self.data.blogTopicsArr.splice( - 1, 1);
                self.update(self.data.blogTopicsArr);
                riot.route("signup_popup");
            } else if (res == 'saved'){
                console.log('blog posted successfully: ', self.data.blogTopicsArr);
                document.getElementById('title').value = '';
                document.getElementById('topicDetails').value = '';
                self.update();
            } else if (typeof res.redirect == 'string'){
                console.log('res.redirect ', res.redirect);
                riot.route(res.redirect)
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
        console.log('err>>>>', err);
        }
    });
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
}
```

Tried three different ways with no luck.

The third approach gives the output with `<br />` tags. How do I preserve new lines?

Output is:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.<br /> Industry's standard text ever since the 1500s, <br /><br />Why do we use it?<br />It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. <br /><br />
```

**Update:**

After successful form post, I am updating the view using riot's `self.update();`  or `this.update()`

**Update2**

Actually I am sending the form data to database and fetching the text back from database to render it. But the text sent to DB has `<br>` tag inserted before saving it in DB so why it displays text as `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.<br /> Industry's standard text ever since the 1500s, <br />` ??

Comment: Tell us please what you want to achieve?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki As mentioned in title, I want to preserve new lines and white spaces inside text. I am using textarea to enter text and on submit, the white space or new lines are not preserved

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I am just posting a form to server. I am using riotjs. I am guessing if this is riotjs issue?

Comment: silly question but did you try:
postTopic(){
    var content = document.getElementById('topicDetails').value;
    var topic = {
        "details": content ,
    }
}

Comment: @Chris Yes I tried that.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Ok I am updating the question now with more code so you will get an idea. I am just updating the view after form post

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Actually you are right. I am sending the text to Database and fetching it again to show the text in the view. But fetching the text that contains `<br/>` should render it correctly right

Comment: @kittu what about using .replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález View = html page

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I guess I need to convert it back to `string.replace(/<br\/>/gi, '\n') : "";`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes text is inserted into div

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález `<div class='col-md-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12'>
                                <p>{data.post_details.details}</p>
                            </div>`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález from database I got the text as `Sample1 Sample1 Sample1<br /><br />Sample1<br />Sample1` and I tried converting to new line like `res.details = res.details.replace(/\s?(<br\s?\/?>)\s?/g, "\r\n");
            self.data.post_details = res;`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Fixed it !!!

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Check my answer below

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

Actually I all had to was add `pre-wrap` like below.

```
<p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">{data.post_details.details}</p>
```

This retained the spacing with new lines as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace the newlines with `<br>` using this `.replace(/\n/g,"<br>")`

```
function postTopic() {
  var content = document.getElementById('topicDetails').value;

  var textcontent = content.replace(/\n/g,"<br>");

  var topic = {
    "details": textcontent,
  }
}
```

Comment: Still the output is like this: `asdasd<br>asd<br>asd<br><br><br>asd`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply handle this when you process the form on the server side. For instance, if your form action is set to "companyForm.php" then in your companyForm.php you could use a function like nl2br, such as:

```
$companyName = nl2br($_POST['companyName']);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

If for whatever reason you absolutely must do this on the client side, you could use [nl2br on php.js](http://locutus.io/php/strings/nl2br/) by adding this:

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {

    if (typeof str === 'undefined' || str === null) {
        return ''
    }

    var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';
    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
}
```

Then use:

```
nl2br(textcontent, false)
```

Comment: But I am not sending the text directly to server. I am calling a function called `postTopic()` which calls ajax to send text to server.

Comment: My edit is in case he needs to use JS. My original answer was just suggesting that this type of thing is typically handled on the server side.

I still think he's got the workflow wrong. Even if the postTopic function sends the text field data to the server with an AJAX call, you'd be able to convert the white space on the server side.

Comment: But he explicitly says the <br /> tag isn't working?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: is_xhtml is not defined

Comment: Some browsers don't handle the null reference well. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: If I  use `is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml == 'null'` with double equals checks for both I guess

Comment: Oh nono, just insert the portion I added that reads if (typeof str === 'undefined' || str === null) {

Comment: You would use nl2br(textcontent, false)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use

`&#10;` as \r and

`&#13;` as \n

Plug those values into your replace function and it should work.

[More info:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area)

Comment: Like `content.replace(/\r?\n/g, '&#13;');`

Comment: and it prints &#13; in the output

Comment: Updated the question. Actually I am fetching the text from DB but it renders with `<br>` tags inside the text when I display it on view(html page). I just checked the DB, it contain text like `asdasd<br>asd<br>asd<br><br><br>asd`