# After the insert string into the MySQL, character '\n' (newline) disappears

Tags: php, mysql, string, newline, sql-insert

I want to insert a similar string into DB, but after inserting the characters "\n" disappear and in DB I see it as new line.

The string which I send:

```
[{"Index":0,"Title":"headline","Content":"first line\nsecond line","Class":"colour1"}]
```

For insert to DB, I use this PHP code and string I send via HTML form with method POST.

```
if ( $action == "save") {
  $notes = $_POST['notes'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO notes (notes) VALUES ('$notes')";
  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    $saved = "Saved...";
  } else {
    $saved =  "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
  }
}
```

When I print variable "$_POST['notes']" or "$notes" before sending via the form, the string is OK, after sending the form and before inserting into DB, the string is OK too.

Comment: Try: `str_replace('\n', '&#13;&#10;', $_POST['notes']);`    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area

Answer (score 1):

While fetching results from database , use nl2br()

Comment: Function nl2br() inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string, but I want to get back same string which I inserting, without new lines, with "\n" character. Is there a similar function which replaces new lines to character \n?

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises due to interpretation of '\n' as '\\n' in MySql. To avoid this conversion,try this approach:
Change your query string before making an insert to database as following:

```
    $notes = $_POST['notes'];
    //This line will replace '\n' with HTML Coded Character Set, but will be interpreted in HTML as \n itself. 
    $notes = str_replace('\n', '&#92;&#110;', $notes);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO notes (notes) VALUES ('$notes')";
```

Answer (score 0):

"\n" is a next line statement, it is correct that MYSql take it as next line. Gotta use nl2br($value) to make it display as next line in html webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You Should use Textarea while inserting data and when you want to show/echo the data use this PHP function to preserve the line breaks echo nl2br($string);

For example

```
        <textarea class="form-control" name="short_desc" required></textarea>
```

and for frontend echo use following function

```
    <?PHP echo nl2br($short_desc);?>
```

It will preserve the line break and show content with breaks on frontend,

Also keep the Mysql data type text for it.