# Rails text_area_tag break line with value

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have an array, and I need to print these value line by line in a `textarea`.

According to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area).

I thought I can print `html` by this way.

```
<textarea id="t">Line 1&#10;Line 2</textarea>
```

Therefore, here is what I wrote.

Note: `@parameter = ["Line1", "Line2"]`

```
<span class="edit">
  <%= text_area_tag('list', @parameter.join('&#10;'))%>
</span>
```

However, I got this

[image]

instead of this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try with or `"\n"`

```
<span class="edit">
  <%= text_area_tag('list', @parameter.join("\n"))%>
</span>
```

[image]

Comment: They both fail.

Comment: try `\n` with double quotes

Comment: I just tested it

Comment: `\n` in double quote is considered as `new line` but not in single quotes

Comment: Thanks, you have been a great help.