# Change paragraph to line break in textarea

Tags: html, asp.net, textarea

This question is for when user is actually typing the text in textarea and not for how to process it afterwards.

When I enter text in textarea and press Enter, and then do a "view source" I see newlines are translated to html paragraphs (<p> and </p>). This causes a big gap between two successive lines. Is there some way of forcing it to use line breaks (<br />)? I tried using CSS but nothing worked (neither it seems I can change font size and type!)

For storing this data in DB, I can replace all <p> with empty string and all </p> with <br /> before processing it so it would display correctly later.

**Update**
I am using an Ajax HTML Text Editor:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="edComment" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="Comment" />
<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender runat="server" ID="heeComment" 
    TargetControlID="edComment" 
    EnableSanitization="false" 
    BehaviorID="heeComment" 
    DisplayPreviewTab="false" 
    DisplaySourceTab="false">
</ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

When I enter "blah<enter>blah<enter><enter>" and in code behind capture the text (i.e. edComment.Text), I see:

```
<p>blah</p><p>blah</p><p><br></p>
```

This is why when I (user), am typing the text, there is such a big gap between two blahs; because they are taken as paragraphs. I am wondering if his can be forced to use <br /> so I would have blah<br />blah<br />.
Not after all is said and done but while I am typing the text.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? Using Google Chrome I don't see any paragraph tags when I view the source after writing in a `<textarea>` element.

Comment: I think you are talking about a HTML text editor (like CKEditor), and not a textarea. Usually you can press `shift` + `enter` to create a line break. But most editor have the option to change the enter behaviour from `<p>` to `<br>` in a config file.

Comment: I updated my post with more info.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your answer is here:

[New line in text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area)

In short: use & # 13 ; & # 10 ; without spaces to create a new line. Example code would help with clarity in the future!