# Replacing double <br> with two new lines not working

Tags: php

So I have the the following html:

```
line 1<br>line 2<br><br>line 4<br><br>line 6
```

And a preg_replace that replaces all break lines with new lines:

```
preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $data.edit_comment->content)
```

However, the output is this:

```
line 1
line 2
line 4
line 6
```

In other words, lline 3 and 5 are disappearing. Why is this happening? I know there are a ton of questions like these on the internet but I haven't seen one that explains why this is happening and how to fix it. I tried replacing `<br>` with `\r\n` but it makes no difference.

Comment: I see multiple lines https://3v4l.org/I7ifB how are you viewing it?

Comment: Looks fine to me. https://3v4l.org/gUPrM

Comment: I view it in a textarea

Comment: That's not a double-`<br>`. That's a `<br>`, newline, `<br>`. Adjust your regex accordingly...

Comment: Sorry, the html text is in a single line. I did it in new lines for visibility.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area

Comment: Are you explicitly targetting double-`<br>`s or need to replace single ones too?

Answer (score 0):

I works fine for me in text area ...

```
<?php $html = 'line 1<br>line 2<br><br>line 4<br><br>line 6'; ?>
<textarea cols='60' rows='8'><?php echo preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $html); ?></textarea>
```

Outputs:

[image: textarea output]