# New line in textarea <br> not interpreted

Tags: html, textarea, newline

I am extremely tired = extremely stupid but I want to get on with this first thing in the morning...

```
<div class=' form-group smhTextArea removeForAjax' style='margin-bottom: 10px'>
  <div class=''>
    <textarea class='form-control message-text-area'  rows='4'
                 name='message<?= $jj ?>' placeholder='New text box <?= $jj ?>'
                 id='message<?= $jj ?>' >
      ID <?= $jj ?> "\n" <br> Msg:<?= $stackContent ?><br>
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output comes out as:

`ID 1 "\n" <br> Msg:4 Mary had a little lamb it's... ??? @ "<br>`

I have looked at lots of answers on here and searched Google but can see nothing.

If this **should** work it is possibly that this is a very ill-formed test page at the moment.

Once again sorry if dumb but passing out here!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New line in text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area)

Comment: I agree BUT with the difficulty of trying to find that answer I would suggest keeping this. I spent a good 20 mins trying all combinations of "html/newline/textarea" etc before I posted this in distress. Maybe the different wording will help someone find the answer. Just a thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a CR/LF `&#13;&#10;` instead of a `<BR>`

```html
<textarea> ID 1 "\n" &#13;&#10; Msg:4 Mary had a little lamb it's... ??? @ "</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks I copied it from the old answer before I saw yours. But you did give the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `<textarea>` element does not render HTML, it actually renders plain text, as its formatted in HTML file. So that means you don't have to use `<br />` tag to start a new line, instead just use the regular line break (press return key on keyboard).

```html
<textarea>Line 1
Line 2

Line 4
</textarea>
```

Comment: Think that might be problematic in grisly php code! IDEs tend to move things to new lines and then spaces get in and so on. I went with the & answer that I got from the old answer. And thanks for the useful thought that `<textarea>` does not render. I did a d'oh when I saw that. The other answer I think arrived first so I have given them the answer but will upvote you for a thoughtful answer. But I suspect this will be pruned as it is a copy of another post.