# How to insert a line feed code into textarea?

Tags: laravel

How to insert a line feed code into a character in textarea?

I'm using laravel5.4, with Formfacade.

this is my code.

Model:

User.php

```
public function getTagAttribute()
{
  $tags = $this->tags->pluck('tag_name')->toArray();
  return implode('\r\n', $tags);
 }

public function tags()
{
  $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
}
```

Blade:

```
{!!Form::textarea('tag', null, [
      'class' => 'form-control keyword',
      ])!!}
```

Output

```
"\r\n" characters are displayed in the textarea.
```

I tried changing '\r\n' to '\n', '< br/>',
but not worked.

anyone help me??

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area).

Comment: I'm sorry. I searched but  could not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change following line:

```
  return implode('\r\n', $tags);
```

to

```
  return implode("\r\n", $tags);
```

There is a big difference between single quote and double quote. Single quote will only except string and won't parse anything.