# Use \n in html as newline

Tags: python, html, css

I am trying to use `\n` as a newline in HTML, using CSS pre-line, but not able to do it.

```
#just-line-break 
{
    white-space: pre-line;
}

#line-break-and-tab 
{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Getting data through python.

```
<p id="just-line-break">
{% if data %}
{{data}}
{% endif %}
</p>
```

Comment: probably a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area

Comment: both should work, but you don't say what you send from the view, and what is the bad result you have ?

Comment: Check whether you are referencing your CSS file properly.

Comment: the data variable is giving output something like this:
\ncheckTestPlanComments.py\n------------------------\nURL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets

and I wanted the \n to be read as a newline.