# Cannot set multiline text in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have an array, each of its elements in a text line:

```js
a = ['line1', 'line2', 'line3'];
```

I want to set the text lines into a textarea, displayed like so:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

I set the text with the following code:

```js
myTxtArea.value = a.join('\n');
```

and it shows like this:

```
line1\nline2\nline3
```

What to do so that the `\n`'s break lines instead of being displayed?

The textarea HTML:
`<textarea autofocus id=laidTxt name=laidTxt class="laidTxt"`
`placeholder="paste PDF text here">KJHKH DSKJH ...`
`</textarea>`

I see

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New line in text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area)

Comment: Try `"\n"` instead of `'\n'`

Comment: I'm did some testing and wasn't able to get the same result as your'se. What browser are u using?

Comment: Lateat Chrome, also tested with next ff.

Comment: But your comment is interestinn, bacause it suggests that there might be something in my HTML. I'll post it.

Comment: @MauricioSipmann added the HTML

Comment: @Michel Tried "\n" instead of '\n', same result (IMO in JS both are the same, unlike in shell scripts)

Comment: @Andam before committing this question I tried a number of the answers in "New line in text area", no luck

Comment: @Andam Fixed. All answers were OK, it was a remaining piece of code I didn't delete that was introducing the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Michel  Fixed. All answers were OK, it was a remaining piece of code I didn't delete that was introducing the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Mauricio Sipman Fixed. All answers were OK, it was a remaining piece of code I didn't delete that was introducing the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @tawfik al Fixed. All answers were OK, it was a remaining piece of code I didn't delete that was introducing the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
for (let index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
 myTxtArea.value += a[index]+'\n';

 }
```

its work with me

Comment: Same result. Even replacing '\n' by '\x0A' (it still displays \n's in the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why it does not work for you but as it shows in the example below it works

```js
a = ['line1', 'line2', 'line3'];

document.getElementById("laidTxt").value = a.join('\n');
```

```html
<textarea autofocus id="laidTxt"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear any doubts, the code I initially posted in the question is OK and works fine.

For the curious: I was applying a `JSON.stringify()` transformation to the joined lines just before setting them into the textarea.
Like so:
`let txt = JSON.stringify( handleText( txtArea.value ) );`
`txtArea.value = txt;`