# How to iterate over a dictionary in Jinja2 using FastAPI?

Tags: python, html, dictionary, jinja2, fastapi

I have a `temp.py` file and I have used FastAPI to return string or a dictionary with 2 get methods one for string another for dictionary.

I also have a `temp.html` file inside templates folder.

I am using `Jinja2Templates` as the template engine in HTML as the frontend view.

If the output result from FastAPI is string, I just want to display, as it is.
But if the output variable is dictionary, I want to iterate over it and print each key and value pair in a new line.

I have tried this piece of code but I am getting `Internal Server error` while calling the get method for printing dictionary output.

### Backend

```py
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


@app.get("/hello")
async def form_get(request: Request):
    output = "HELLO"
    return templates.TemplateResponse('temp.html', context={'request': request, 'result': output})


@app.get("/dic")
async def form_post(request: Request):
    test = {1: 56, 2: 45, 3: 46, 4: 35, 5: 69}
    return templates.TemplateResponse('temp.html', context={'request': request, 'result': test})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("temp:app", reload=True)
```

### Frontend

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    {% if result == "HELLO" %}
        {{ result }}
    {% else %}
        {% for key, value in result.item() %}
            {{ key }} : {{ value }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71121812/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74237972/17865804).

Comment: @Chris Yeah for sure, I will do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Backend

```py
from fastapi import Request

@app.get('/')
async def main(request: Request):
    d = {1: 56, 2: 45, 3: 46, 4: 35, 5: 70}
    return templates.TemplateResponse('temp.html', context={'request': request, 'result': d})
```

### Frontend

The error is in your Jinja2 template when trying to access the `items` of the dictionary (you are actually missing an 's' at the end)—for future reference, make sure to have a look at the console running the app when coming across `Internal Server Error`; it should provide you with details regarding the error. That should be:

```
{% for key, value in result.items() %}
    {{ key }} : {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Related answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74237972/17865804) as well. Additionally, I would suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) to understand the difference between defining your endpoint with normal `def` and `async def` endpoints.