# Displaying a list of dictionaries with Jinja2

Tags: jinja2, fastapi

1. I've got a FastAPI endpoint that's returning a list of dictionaries:

   @router.get("/customers/")
   async def read_customers(*,session: Session = Depends(get_session)):
   customers = session.query(Customers).all()
   return customers

output:

```
[{"customerName":"Signal Gift Stores","customerNumber":112},...]
```

2. How do I modify the endpoint for Jinja2? Everything I've tried gives me some kind of an error indicating that a list object can't be used.
3. It also appears that I can't use session in the TemplateResponse context because "context must include a 'request' key."

   @router.get("/customers/")
   async def read_customers(*,session: Session = Depends(get_session)):
   customers = session.query(Customers).all()
   return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", **What do I do here?**)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74584131/17865804) answer your question? You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74588435/17865804) helpful as well.