# Azure AD B2C language customization adding new line to a string not working

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have Azure AD B2C authentication in my application and I have enabled internationalization support. I have customized the sign in page the language file provided by Microsoft is in json format. I need to add break line or new line between some of my strings it doesn't works.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-user-flow

I added `\n` and also `\\n` and `<br />` `&#13;&#10; &NewLine;` its not working.

```
  {
  "ElementType": "UxElement",
  "ElementId": null,
  "StringId": "forgotpassword_link",
  "Override": true,
  "Value": "Forgot your password? (Vous avez oublié?)"
},
{
  "ElementType": "UxElement",
  "ElementId": null,
  "StringId": "heading",
  "Override": true,
  "Value": "Sign in  \n \\n (Ouverture de session)"
},
```

is there a way I add breakline between my string ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the html break tag `<br/>` instead of `\n`?

Comment: I did its not working, it just display the <br /> withing the text, it reads it as text not html

Comment: Have you also tried &NewLine; or &#10;  like shown here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/how-to-add-a-new-line-in-textarea-element

Comment: Yes, I did its not working and its displaying them as text