# Django show list of strings in textarea, each string from new line

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a list `lst=['apple', 'pear', 'peach']`.

I want to show each item in textarea from new line (removing redundant subspaces).

```
            <textarea>
                    {% for item in lst %}
                        {{ item }}
                        {% if not forloop.last %}<br/>{% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
            </textarea>
```

This code doesn't work. `<br/>`s are shown as they are. And there are redundant whitespaces at the beginning of the textarea and between the items.

Comment: Share the view that you are passing it as a context.

Comment: I pass lst into template.

Comment: But how do you do that? Share the code, please.

Comment: You can use {{ item|linebreaksbr }} linebreaksbr  filter and manage textarea by writing that code in single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<textarea>` tag is very stupid:) in your template there is no place for new line and space:

```
<textarea>{% for item in lst %}{{ item }}{% if not forloop.last %}&#13;&#10;{% endif %}{% endfor %}</textarea>
```

It need to be in one line or it will break.

`&#10;` Line Feed and `&#13;` Carriage Return as @Bukudan explain in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8627926/13773284