# Rails/ERB with Redcarpet: HTML disappearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, redcarpet

If I start `rails console` and enter:

```
Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new).render("line 1  \nline 2").html_safe
```

(Remember in markdown 2 spaces before a line break means a forced line break)
I get the expected: `<p>line 1<br>\nline 2</p>\n`

But if I use this code in ERB, all I see in my page source is the original text wrapped in a `<p>`. The line break escape characters are preserved, but the 2 spaces are gone and there is no `<br>`.

What gives? Thanks for your wisdom. Extra kudos if you explain how I could isolate the problem myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround that I settled on is to use the "hard wrap" option in Redcarpet. This actually is totally acceptable for my use case but I am still curious, so I'll change the accepted answer if anyone comes up with a solution to the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I belive You chould do something like

```
...render("line 1  \nline 2".gsub(/\n/, '<br/>')).html_safe
```

Well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137393/rails-add-a-line-break-into-a-text-area)